# Is there a way to drop all tables or truncate inside a postgres testcontainer

Tags: java, postgresql, junit5, quarkus, testcontainers

I'm looking for a way to keep my component tests self contained.
So to achieve this behavior, in some of the tests I need to have a 'clean database' or at least a 'clean table'. I still couldn't find a way to do this inside a testcontainer.
So here is what I've tried so far:
My container setup class:

public class PostgreSqlTestContainer implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

```
public static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> POSTGRES = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:alpine");

@Override
public Map<String, String> start() {
    POSTGRES.start();         
    return some_db_config_as_per_doc;
}

@Override
public void stop() {        
    POSTGRES.stop();
}
```

Here is the tests class:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(PostgreSqlTestContainer.class)
class UserResourcesTest {

  @Test
  scenario_one(){
     // create a new user
     // do some stuff (@POST.. check HTTP == 201) 
  }

  @Test
  scenario_two(){
     // create new user
     // do some stuff (@POST.. check HTTP == 201) (pass)
     // look for all users on database
     // do more stuff (@GET..  check HTTP == 200) (pass)
     // assert that only 1 user was found
     // since scenario_one should not interfere with scenario_two (fail)
  }

}
```

The second scenario fails since some 'dirty' from the first test was still on the db container.
I've tried to stop/start the container for each test. (very, very slow process, and sometimes I get an error, and very slow again).

```
    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        PostgreSqlTestContainer.POSTGRES.stop();
        PostgreSqlTestContainer.POSTGRES.start();
    }
```

Also tried to truncate the table / drop the whole db:

```
    @Inject
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeEach
    private void rollBack(){
        truncate();
    }

    void truncate(){
      Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_name");
      nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
    }
```

I'm looking for any workaround for this problem, I just want to somehow use a `@BeforeEach` to clean up the DB before each test. I mean, all I want is a clean environment for each test.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re using Panache and Active Record pattern, you can do this:

```
@BeforeEach
@Transactional
public void cleanUp() {
   MyEntity.deleteAll();
}
```

If you are using repositories then simply inject your repository and call the deleteAll() method.

And there is also *@TestTransactional* available for unit tests. This will simply rollback any changes to the db after the test has finished.

Btw, I’m typing from my phone, so apologies for any syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template test database with the name `test_template`.

After each test,

1. disconnect all sessions from the test database (not required with PostgreSQL v13):

   ```
   SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
   FROM pg_stat_activity
   WHERE datname = 'test';
   ```
2. drop the database with

   ```
   DROP DATABASE test;
   ```

   In v13, use the additional `FORCE` option.
3. create a new test database with

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE test TEMPLATE test_template;
   ```

Note: you have to enable autocommit in the JDBC driver for `CREATE DATABASE` and `DROP DATABASE` to work.

Comment: Can you provide some example?

Comment: I did, didn't I?

Comment: By using the same way the doing ATM (`createNativeQuery("DROP DATABASE db_name");` I'm getting an error: Enable to execute update/delete query statement.

Comment: Do you get a PostgreSQL error message along with that meaningless message, perhaps as a nested exception? Did you enable autocommit?

Comment: I meant, 'Unable to execute...' not enable... hehe

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this:

1. Remove the static clause from the container definition. It will force it to create the container on every start() execution.

   PostgreSQLContainer<?> POSTGRES ....
2. You can also remove the stop in the @beforeach I think it is not necesary
3. You can create the tables when you start the container providing the schema SQL:

   ```
    PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer< ("postgres:14-alpine")
              .withDatabaseName("db")
              .withUsername("username")
              .withPassword("password")
              .withCopyFileToContainer(
                   MountableFile.forClasspathResource("/schema.sql"),
                   "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
              );
   ```
4. And if you want to insert some data in depending of your test method you can do something like this and call it in the beginning of your test:

   ```
    private void loadData(String scriptPath) {
        try {
            postgresContainer.copyFileToContainer(
                 MountableFile.forClasspathResource(scriptPath),
                 "/data/import.sql"
            );
            postgresContainer.execInContainer(
                 "psql",
                 "-U",
                 postgresContainer.getUsername(),
                 "-d",
                 postgresContainer.getDatabaseName(),
                 "-f",
                 "/data/import.sql"
           );
       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
   }
   ```